# VisNetwork and dashboardSidebar create footer when defining height

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, visnetwork

I am developping a Shiny app relying on [VisNetwork](https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/) to plot dynamic overviews of our company's network.

Since the network is rather large, I'd like that it can extends vertically so as to make it more readable. Currently it works but then the network overlaps with the dashboardSidebar, at the bottom:
[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYAU0.jpg).

Why does the dashboardSidebar extends horizontally at the bottom, isn't only supposed to be left-sided ?
Is it possible to remove this footer?

Here is a simple reproducible example (I believe the issue arises when setting up the Height argument of the VisOptions function):

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)
library(shinydashboard)

# User interface
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Network", titleWidth = 220),
  
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(width = 220,
                   sidebarUserPanel(name = "CTU",image = "unibe_logo_mh.png"), 
                   sidebarMenu(id = "tab",
                               menuItem('CTU Division',
                                        menuSubItem("Data Management", tabName = "datamanagement", icon = icon("database")),
                                        menuSubItem("Statistics", tabName = "statistics", icon = icon("chart-area")),
                                        menuSubItem("Clinical Study Management", tabName = "studymanagement", icon = icon("laptop-medical")),
                                        menuSubItem("Monitoring", tabName = "monitoring", icon = icon("check")), # Would like to use the "magnifying-glass"
                                        menuItem("Quality Management", tabName = "qualitymanagement", icon = icon("broom"))),
                               radioButtons("projectlab", label = "Project labels", choices = c("IDs", "Names"), inline=T),
                               selectInput("servicetype", label = "Service", choices = c("\a", "Basic", "Full", "Light")),
                               checkboxGroupInput('projecttype', "Project types", c("External", "Consulting","Internal","FTE"), selected = "External"), 
                               selectInput("dlfsupport", label = "DLF support", choices = c("\a", "Yes", "No")),
                               selectInput("cdms", label = "CDMS", choices = c("\a","REDCap", "secuTrial", "Webspirit")),
                               checkboxGroupInput('tables', "Export tables", c("Time Bookings","Workers","Projects"), selected = c("Time Bookings","Workers","Projects")), 
                               downloadButton("DownloadReport", "Download Report", style = "margin: 5px 5px 35px 35px; "))), 
  
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar { font-size: 15px; }"))), # Changing sidebar font sizes
                # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
                fluidRow(
                  visNetworkOutput("network") # Unique name for an output
                ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  getDiagramPlot <- function(nodes, edges){
    v <- visNetwork(
      nodes, 
      edges
    ) %>%
      visPhysics(stabilization = TRUE, enabled = F) %>%
      visOptions(height = "1800", highlightNearest = T, nodesIdSelection = T, selectedBy= list(variable="group",multiple=T)) %>%
      visEdges(color = list(highlight = "red")) %>% # The colour of the edge linking nodes
      visLayout(improvedLayout = TRUE) %>%
      visEdges(arrows = edges$arrows) %>%
      visInteraction(multiselect = F) %>%
      visEvents(doubleClick = "function(nodes) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
            ;}")
    return(v)
  }
  
  testFunction <- function(node_id){
    print(paste("The selected node ID is:", node_id))
  }
  
  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = 1:3, group = c("group1","group1","group2"), value = c(10,10,11), color=c("#E41A1C","#48A462","#4A72A6"))
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3), width = c(0.4,0.8))
  
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork(
    getDiagramPlot(nodes, edges)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$current_node_id,{
    testFunction(input$current_node_id)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Best,

C.

Comment: Do you have `dashboardPage(footer = NULL)`?  Did you accidentally have an unnamed argument that got interpreted as a footer?

Comment: Try wrapping the output in a `fluidPage` or `fluidRow` and please provide us with a reproducible example.

Comment: @MichaelDewar `dashboardPage(footer = NULL)` returns an error:
Error in dashboardPage(footer = NULL, dashboardHeader(title = "CTU Network"),  : 
  unused argument (footer = NULL).

Comment: @ismirsehregal my output is already wrapped in a `fluidPage` (changing it for `fluidRow` doesn't change anything).

Comment: I still haven't found a solution, anyone could help ? (I have just provided a simple reproducible example)